# How to write .NET regular expression for floating value (5,2)?

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex

Hi i need to write a regular expression for float value `(5,2)`

As per my understanding `(5,2)` means

1. Total length cannot exceed 5 digits i.e. `999.99`
2. Digits before decimal is 3 and after decimal is 2 i.e. `999.99`

I wrote this: `ValidationExpression="(^\d{0,3}[.]?\d{0,2}$)"` but this is accepting `9999` and `99999` which is wrong because in both case before decimal is more than 3 digits.

Please help?

Comment: Are leading zeroes allowed? Can an integer part of `0` be dropped? Is `1.` legal?

Comment: @Kobi: Two people working on the same thing at the same time :)

Answer (score 4):

For your case of 0-3 digits before dot and 0-2 after dot:

```
[-+]?[0-9]{0,3}\.?[0-9]{1,2}
```

Notice the subtle difference of requiring at least one number *after* the dot. If you allow 0 numbers after the dot, you will match just `.`, which is not a number.

The general convention on floating point numbers is to allow starting with the decimal separator and write just the decimal part (.e.g `.123` means `0.123`), so I'd recommend you to do that unless you have other requirements to regard.

This will match:

```
.1
0.1
0.01
100.02
-3.01
```

If you want to, you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

NOTE: If you need multi-language support, different locales have different decimal separators (Norwegian has `,`, for instance).

General matcher for floating point numbers (from [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)):

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

Validation ("is this string a floating point number") needs anchoring:

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$
```

And finally, here's an expression allowing exponents (e.g. -0.1e-9):

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest

```
ValidationExpression = @"^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$)"
```

This requires at least one (integer) digit, and if there is a decimal part, it has to be one or two digits long. So this will match

```
1
1.0
0.12
999.99
```

but fail

```
.1
1.
000001.0
9999
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the question mark, it made the dot optional.

If you want a regex that match "123.45", "123.4" and "123" but NOT "123.", use this:

```
(^\d{0,3}([.]\d{0,2})?$)
```

in wich the optional part is the entire decimal part of the number

Answer (score 0):

\d{0,3} means "between zero and 3 digits"

You should use

```
(^\d{3}\.\d{2]$)
```

If you do not want leading zeroes, use this one instead:

```
(^[1-9]\d{2}\.\d{2]$)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"^\d{1,12}(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$"
```

means 1-12 digits before separator, then separator (dot or comma), then 0-2 digits after separator, i.e.:

```
9
99
999,1
9999,22
(and the same with dot)
```